# Oracle 12c: creating nonunique ID

Tags: sql, oracle, sequence, oracle12c

I would like to create nonunique auto-increment ID on a table in the following way.  (Oracle 12c + PL/SQL developer 12.0.6.1835)

Suppose we have three columns:

```
ENTITY_NATURAL_KEY (VARCHAR)
SOME_DATE_PARAMETER (DATE)
ID (INT) /*<-- this is our ID*/
```

- For every row `WHERE ENTITY_NATURAL_KEY = 123 and SOME_DATE_PARAMETER= '2020-01-01'`  I would like to `SET ID = 1` (value is for example)
- If
  `ENTITY_NATURAL_KEY = 123` (remains the same) and
  `SOME_DATE_PARAMETER` changes **for only 1 day** (`SOME_DATE_PARAMETER= '2020-01-02'`), I would like ID to **remain the same** `SET ID = 1`
- Else if `ENTITY_NATURAL_KEY = 123`
  (remains the same) and `SOME_DATE_PARAMETER` **changes for 2 or more
  days** (for example `SOME_DATE_PARAMETER= '2020-01-03'`), I would like ID to change (add increment)

Now, how to do that? :) thx a lot in advance

Comment: I don't clearly understand your problem: do you want an auto incrementing id or this id must be always 1 or 2 depending on the date value?

Comment: hello, I need auto-incrementing id. will edit the question to make it more clear

Comment: @GrigoryP . . . "Non-unique auto-incrementing" does not parse.  Auto-incrementing is functionality specifically to create unique values.  *Sample data* would be very helpful -- more helpful than hard to follow rules.